# Parsing RSS Feeds into an iOS App

Tags: ios, rss, plist, nsxmlparser

I am building and app that will need to parse several RSS feeds, so I am trying to get this theory sorted in my head:-)

I am reading up on NSXMLParser and I have had a look at MWFeedPaser.
Looking at all that code I understand it is going to take time before I understand what it exactly doing.

My initial Idea was to populate a Plist with RSS Links as I have categories that have different feeds and that way I would be able to manage that.

Is that a bad way to go? 
What are the pro's and con's of Plists in this scenario??

The App is designed in a UIViewController using a TableView rather than a UITableViewController if it makes a difference.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking here. The question title talks about parsing RSS feeds, but the only actual question I see here is about whether a plist is an appropriate data structure to hold URLs. What are you actually looking for here?

Comment: On a separate note, I wrote my own RSS parser 4 years ago, called [feedparser](https://github.com/kballard/feedparser). I have not seen MWFeedParser before. I'm curious as to how it compares.

Comment: Yeah i can see the issue:-) Well the goal is to populate a TableView with a RSS feed, but I need to group different feeds into the same view and when you select a Cell you then see the actual feed - hence the Plist approach. Would you even touch Plists in this case??

Comment: cool I had a look into your parser, but it I gotta see if I can manage to use in my iOS app - I know they are very similar, but I haven't done OSX development yet to pickup on some essential differences.

Comment: feedparser was created primarily for iOS, although it should work on both iOS and desktop. From reading the README on MWFeedParser it seems the primary difference is MWFeedParser gives you a streaming API whereas my feedparser gives you a DOM structure that represents the whole feed.

Comment: Well, that and MWFeedParser claims it parses Atom while feedparser never got full Atom support (because I never needed it for the project I wrote feedparser for, and nobody else has contributed patches to implement it), although it shouldn't be hard to add Atom support if necessary.

Comment: ah yeah I see now - I do need it for streaming audio files so i'll keep looking into a solution. MWFeedParser is not ARC compatible yet and it is a bit of a pain to work with :-)

Comment: What do you mean, for streaming audio files? How you parse the RSS file really has no bearing on how you download (or stream) any enclosures. And practically speaking, RSS files should not be large enough that streaming vs. DOM makes any real difference in resource usage.

Comment: ok - thanks for the info, like I said it is a new area for me - gotta look into it.